# use outer apply to find for each row have a record based on first result from detail table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables; `PROBLEM` for problem (as master) with group of problem  and `PROBLEM_LOG` (as detail)

PROBLEM

```
PROBLEM_ID      PROBLEM          PGROUP
1               Line Down        Network
2               Node Down        Network
3               hardware error   Hardware
4               PM               Hardware
5               disk error       Hardware
```

PROBLEM_LOG

```
TERM        PROBLEM           DOWN_DATE
S1DIP0314   Service           15-03-26
S1DIP0314   PM                15-01-01
S1DIP0314   Service           15-01-02
S1DIP0314   disk error        15-01-06
S1DIP0314   Hardware error    15-01-28
```

At first I  find `TERM` that have a `PROBLEM = 'PM'` (in this case I will use `dateadd+7` days)

```
SELECT  TERM,PROBLEM,DOWN_DATE
  FROM [PROBLEM_LOG]
  WHERE PROBLEM = 'PM'
```

But my problem is when I find a `problem = 'PM'` From the date that have `PM + 7` days that have Other `PGROUP = 'Hardware'` or not
with my example there is more 1 Problem within 7 days there is a `'Disk Error'`
the result should be this

```
TERM        PROBLEM       DOWN_DATE
S1DIP0314   PM            15-01-01
S1DIP0314   disk error    15-01-06
```

And when I found more problem then find the more problem from within 30 days from last problem that I found

```
TERM        PROBLEM           DOWN_DATE
S1DIP0314   PM                15-01-01
S1DIP0314   disk error        15-01-06
S1DIP0314   Hardware error    15-01-28
```

I must use outer apply to make this condition come true

I tried this

```
SELECT pt.term,
       pts.problem,
       pts.down_date
  FROM PROBLEM_LOG pt
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ATM ON pt.TERM = atm.term
       OUTER APPLY( 
                    SELECT px.term,
                           px.problem,
                           px.down_date
                      FROM problem_log px
                           LEFT JOIN problem pf ON pf.PROBLEM = px.problem
                      WHERE px.PROBLEM = pt.problem
                        AND PGROUP = 'Hardware' ) pts
  WHERE pt.PROBLEM = 'PM'
  AND ('20' + pt.DOWN_DATE + ' ' + down_time) <= DATEADD( day,7,('20' + pt.DOWN_DATE + ' ' + pt.DOWN_TIME))) pts;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need all logs of problems with same group so you can use a simple query like this:

```
Declare @Term varchar(10) = 'S1DIP0314'
Declare @Problem varchar(10) = 'PM'

select pt.TERM, pt.PROBLEM, pt.DOWN_DATE 
from problem_log pt
where pt.TERM = @Term 
    AND pt.PROBLEM IN (SELECT p.PROBLEM FROM problem p 
                       WHERE p.PGROUP = (SELECT p1.PGROUP FROM problem p1 
                                          WHERE p1.PROBLEM = @Problem))
```